# ec2-commans specify the vpc and subnet of launch configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I´m trying to create a launch configuration with ec2-commands, the documentation says this:

```
create-launch-configuration
--launch-configuration-name <value>
[--image-id <value>]
[--key-name <value>]
[--security-groups <value>]
[--classic-link-vpc-id <value>]
[--classic-link-vpc-security-groups <value>]
[--user-data <value>]
[--instance-id <value>]
[--instance-type <value>]
[--kernel-id <value>]
[--ramdisk-id <value>]
[--block-device-mappings <value>]
[--instance-monitoring <value>]
[--spot-price <value>]
[--iam-instance-profile <value>]
[--ebs-optimized | --no-ebs-optimized]
[--associate-public-ip-address | --no-associate-public-ip-address]
[--placement-tenancy <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton]
```

The problem is the VPC and the subnet, I´m not using the default VPC and I have a subnet in my own VPC, I´m trying to launch my LC with this command:

```
aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name ec2_command_lc --image-id ami-350e2f5f --instance-type t2.micro --key-name smartpublicity --classic-link-vpc-id vpc-e0caa885 --classic-link-vpc-security-groups sg_client --user-data Desktop/Code/miscript.sh
```

But I get an error, it says that the SG doesnt exist in my default vpc, I would like to specify the vpc where I have my infrastructure.

I did´t find about this, also I tried with --classic-link-vpc-id but I dont know what its this and I think this is other think of AWS.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and mask your vpc-id etc id , because those are all unique inside AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, in the command I was writting the name of my security group and you must write the id of the sg